# Capturing numbers in a specific range using swift

Tags: ios, swift, logic

Swift 5 iOS 12.x

A stupid question I am sure, but I having a moment.

I got values from -100 to 100. I am interested in the values less than -10 or greater than 10. I wrote this code.

```
func returnPod() -> String {
defer {
   pods.removeAll()
}
var aPitch: Float? = 0
var aRoll: Float? = 0
var aYaw: Float? = 0
for peas in pods {
  print("peas \(peas)")
  if peas.pitch! < Float(-10) && peas.pitch! > Float(10) {
      // capture an average everything below 10, above 10
      aPitch = aPitch! + peas.pitch!
      aRoll = aRoll! + peas.roll!
      aYaw = aYaw! + peas.yaw!
  } else {
      // drop everything return zero this should happen if pitch is between -10 and 10.
    return "@:0:0:0\n"
  }
}
return("@:\(String(describing: aRoll!)):\(String(describing: aPitch!)):\(String(describing: aYaw!))")
```

}

But it doesn't work, it just returns everything... What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Peas.pitch! can't be >10 and <-10, replace '&&' with '||'

Comment: That was it! Thank you!!